# URI order is reversed after Xtext 2.9.2 version migration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext, emf

Recently xtext migration done in my development environment. Resource URI list is reversed after migrating to the version 2.9.2. I was using org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IStorage2UriMapper class to get the specific file extension resources from the project.

Before migration: org.eclipse.xtext.ui_2.6.0.v201405210727.jar

After migration: org.eclipse.xtext.ui_2.9.2.v201603040440.jar

Before output:

```
/resource/example/root/B.txt
/resource/example/root/A.txt
/resource/example/enum/enum.txt
/resource/example/data/datatype.txt
```

Output after migration:

```
/resource/example/data/datatype.txt
/resource/example/enum/enum.txt
/resource/example/root/A.txt
/resource/example/root/B.txt
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you actually do? Please elaborate

Comment: p.s: maps are ususally not sorted => you may have to sort manually

Comment: Out of the project files we are generating some xml file. Now the xml file content is reversed due to the reverse order of this file list.                           How to sort URI order in the map?

Comment: this is more a java question than a xtext question?!?

Comment: My question is how to resolve this problem i meant we can't sort URI list as like normal ArrayList.We need special handling to sort URI(Sort by folder name in that folder will be recursive). And wanted to know what was the change from org.eclipse.xtext.ui_2.6.0.v201405210727.jar to org.eclipse.xtext.ui_2.9.2.v201603040440.jar

Comment: there might be some internal change (i dont know, you will have to look into the git history https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/tree/v2.9.2/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/resource) since i still dont know which method you use and how you iterate and what your expected sorting criteria is it is hard to advice)

Comment: p.s: did you update xtext only or did you update eclipse as well?

Comment: Updated through update site .in development environment. I am using IStorage2UriMapper.allEntries method i am using to get list of files which is present in the project.

Comment: that method gives you a map. what do you do with it?

Comment: I will loop keyset of the map(URI) and generate xml file content from the URI... Because of this case my xml content is reversed now. For example<File><Name>root</Name><Name>pack</Name></File> ..After migration content is reversed and generating like <File><Name>pack</Name><Name>root</Name></File>

Comment: And turning the set to a list and sorting by toString does not work